# How to change the DocumentRoot on cloudControl?

Tags: cloud, slim, cloudcontrol

I need to set a sub directory as DocumentRoot to run my application on slim framework. Is there any way to do this?

I tried with htaccess files without success:
root:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^$ www/ [L]
RewriteRule (.*) www/$1 [L]
```

sub dir:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA,L]
```

Answer (score 4):

Just create a `.ccconfig.yaml` in your application-root.

Content should be

```
BaseConfig:
    WebContent: /www
    AdminEmail: [email]
```

That should work. If you need to you can define your own PHP-config-settings in this file too.

Comment: hey, can you point us to the documentation link of this file? I looked over a bunch of doc pages and found no reference to the file :(

Comment: strange, only currently available reference I could find is [this here](https://www.cloudcontrol.com/dev-center/Guides/PHP/Symfony%201.4)

Comment: Yeah, DotCloud documentation sucks so hard... Some time after this post i discovered they don't even recommend using this config file anymore, but this is not written ANYWHERE. I had to mail them for they to tell me this. And they they said "stop mailing us, this is a paid service, stupid". Conclusion: the documentation is totally awful **just to force you to pay for support**. Not gonna work with me. I get stuff done more easily paying for infrastructure in other PaaS. Stupid and unfair strategy.

Comment: @Igoru: i think both Vied12 and Denis are talking about CloudControl (baes in Berlin). Is it in any way related to dotcloud (based in the US)? Because i had only good experiences with the cloudcontrol staff so far.

Comment: Ooops! I really meant CloudControl. DotCloud is another provider that have even discontinued free accounts sometime ago. Maybe I was with that in mind when was commenting here, sorry.
But I still think their documentation is simply awful and the support virtually does not exist, as it's in fact, paid. They are kind but that doesn't mean the support service is good - at least not when you're not paying.